# How to implement and register interfaces in different bundles and under a central OSGi service?

Tags: osgi, bundles

I have a question regarding registering/using services in OSGi between bundles.  I have two bundles, Bundle A - with my core service that binds multiple "handlers" to a map (similar to a factory) and Bundle B - which implements additional handler interface(s).

My expectation was that other bundles could implement the interface(s) and they could be registered with the single service in Bundle A so that when I invoke that core service I could lookup the appropriate handler and process it.  I want the implementations of the handler to be provided from other bundles.

I am working off of this example:

**Multiple Cardinality OSGI @References Using SCR Annotations**
'http://architectslog.wordpress.com/2013/02/18/multiple-cardinality-osgi-references-using-scr-annotations.'

Within the core bundle, my handler implementations bind properly.  In my other bundles the services are being registered by not being bound to the core service.

So, my question is, can I register different implementations of and interface located in other bundles in Bundle A like this?

**Bundle A - Handler Service:**

```
@Component
@Service(value = IContentService.class)
public class ContentService implements IContentService
{
    @Reference(
        referenceInterface = IContentHandler.class,
        cardinality = ReferenceCardinality.MANDATORY_MULTIPLE,
        bind = Constants.OSGI_BIND_METHOD,
        unbind = Constants.OSGI_UNBIND_METHOD,
        policy = ReferencePolicy.DYNAMIC)
    private final Map<String, IContentHandler> handlers = Maps.newHashMap();


    protected void bind(final IContentHandler handler)
    {
        final Content h = handler.getClass().getAnnotation(Content.class);
        if (h != null)
        {
            final String id = getHandlerId(h);
            this.handlers.put(id, handler);
        }
    }
```

**Bundle A - Handler Implementation (registers fine):**

```
@Component
@Service(value = IContentHandler.class)
@Content(name = "bean")
public class BeanContentHandler implements IContentHandler
{
    public IContentBean process(final Resource resource, final ContentOptions options) throws ContentException
    {
        ...
```

**Bundle B - Handler Implementation (does not register):**

```
@Component
@Service(value = IContentHandler.class)
@Content(name = "sample")
public class SampleHandler implements IContentHandler
{
    @Override
    public IContentBean process(Resource resource, ContentOptions options) throws ContentException
    {
        ...
```

Comment: Your set-up looks OK unless (1) bundle B does not import (via `Import-Package`) the interfaces from bundle A (exported via `Export-Package`) or (2) your DS implementation does some kind of proxying that makes the annotation disappear. Can you please check or post your manifest files to verify (1)?

Comment: Interesting you would mention proxying.  I switched over to using iPOJO to see what happens and the binding worked fine cross bundle but the JCROM annotations failed if the abstract class was in one bundle and the implementation was in another.

As a note, I have three bundles - A:Commons (API), B:Impls, and C:Impls.

A:Commons:
Exports the interfaces.

B:Impls:
Imports A Commons

C:Impls:
Imports A commons

Comment: I question the use of annotations here: if the user of a service needs the annotation (in this case the `Content` annotation), it should either be part of the interface or part of the service properties. In this case I would go for the service property. This automatically solves the issue with proxies (if any).

Comment: Actually, that annotation is the least of my concerns and seems to be working fine.  The annotations in question are the JCROM mapping annotations.  When separated across bundles only the derived class annotations are native, the rest appear to be proxied.

Comment: As for using the service property, that is a good suggestion and I will change that.

Comment: Must of been something jacked in my import/export packages.  I cleaned up the POMs and switched to iPOJO (for other reasons) and everything seems to be working.